# Execute Apps Script based value selected in Drop-down list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good afternoon,[image]

I have a Google Sheets that contains a Summary Sheet and approx. 20 sub tabs. On the Summary Sheet, I have created a Drop-down list which lists each of the sub-tabs.

When a user selects a specific sub-tab from the Drop-down list then clicks the Clear Button, I want the amounts from a specified range of rows to be Cleared within the tab.

Currently I have a separate function for each Sheet to cleared. I'm try to have this consolidated into one function.

In the picture attached, the Drop-down list is provided in

```
Summary!J4
```

Snippet of drop-down list

```
--> Planning
--> Framing
--> Foundation
--> ALL SHEETS
```

I attached a Code snippet and picture for clarification. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
function clearPlanningfields() {

 var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Planning");

 var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

 var response=ui.alert("Reset Confirmation", "Do you want to Clear the Sheets?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

 if(response==ui.Button.NO){

   return;

 }

 shUserForm.getRange('H5:H13').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H17:H26').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H30:H31').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H35:H41').setValue('');


 shUserForm.getRange('O5:O13').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O17:O26').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O30:O31').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O35:O41').setValue(false);

 shUserForm.getRange('N4').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N16').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N29').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N34').setValue(0.00);

 myGoogleSheet.toast("Amounts have been Reset from selected Sheet");

return true;

}



function clearFramingfields() {

 var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Framing");

 var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

 var response=ui.alert("Reset Confirmation", "Do you want to Clear the Sheets?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

 if(response==ui.Button.NO){

   return;

 }

 shUserForm.getRange('H5:H19').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H23:H42').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H46:H66').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H70:H84').setValue('');


 shUserForm.getRange('O5:O19').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O23:O42').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O46:O66').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O70:O84').setValue(false);

 shUserForm.getRange('N4').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N22').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N45').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N69').setValue(0.00);

 myGoogleSheet.toast("Amounts have been Reset from selected Sheet");

return true;

}



function clearFoundationfields() {

 var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Foundation");

 var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

 var response=ui.alert("Reset Confirmation", "Do you want to Clear the Sheets?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

 if(response==ui.Button.NO){

   return;

 }

 shUserForm.getRange('H5:H10').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H14:H22').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H26:H41').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H45:H55').setValue('');
 shUserForm.getRange('H59:H62').setValue('');


 shUserForm.getRange('O5:O10').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O14:O22').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O26:O41').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O45:O55').setValue(false);
 shUserForm.getRange('O59:O62').setValue(false);

 shUserForm.getRange('N4').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N13').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N25').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N44').setValue(0.00);
 shUserForm.getRange('N58').setValue(0.00);

 myGoogleSheet.toast("Amounts have been Reset from selected Sheet");

return true;

}
```

[Link Dummy Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xd2f4KDmccg9J9Twkhk8wtOvrTJjlwvXPFXwYdZI1ZY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try creating an object with drop down names for properties and let each property point to an internal object that contains the three rangeLists. One for each '',false and 0.00.  The once you have the drop down name you can run a foreach for each rangelist and set them to the values listed in the object..

Comment: As an example this might be the object initialized with just the planning data `const obj = {"Planning":{clear:['H5:H13','H17:H26','H30:H31','H35:H41'],false:['O5:O13','O17:O26','O30:O31','O35:O41'],zero:['N4','N16','N29','N34']}}`

Comment: Please share a dummy sheet for replication purposes. Kindly check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You just need to thinking of a way to associate all of the required data with the names in the drop down list once you have all of the data organized into a javascript object then you will have a lot less code to write because everything feeds off of the data.

Comment: Sure, I have added a Link to a snippet of the spreadsheet, 'Dummy Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

> ***NOTE**: This answer is intended to serve as a starting point or reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

Perhaps you can try this tweaked script below. This identifies automatically which rows are to be cleared based on the selected sheet tab.

### Script

```
function clearFields() {
  //Get the sheet tab selection from the drop-down
  var tabReference = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary').getRange('J4').getValue();
  //Pass the sheet tab to be cleared
  var rawRowData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(tabReference).getDataRange().getValues();
  //Used the column 9 as reference
  var reference = rawRowData.map((cell, row) => [row + 1, cell[8]]);
  reference.shift();

  //Find the ranges needed to be cleared
  var cleanRowData = reference.map(data => data[1] === '' ? "x" : data[0] + "|");
  var rangeChunks = cleanRowData.join('').split('x').filter(data => data != '');
  var startEndRows = rangeChunks.map(x => [x.split('|').filter(_ => _)[0], x.split('|').filter(_ => _)[x.split('|').filter(_ => _).length - 1]]);

  //Reference on what columns to be cleared
  var columns = ['H', 'O', 'N'];

  //Clear the ranges
  columns.forEach(col => {
    startEndRows.forEach(range => {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(tabReference).getRange(`${col}${range[0]}:${col}${range[1]}`).setValue(col == 'H' ? '' : col == 'O' ? false : col == 'N' && 0.00)
      console.log(`Cleared range: ${col}${range[0]}:${col}${range[1]} replaced with '${col == 'H' ? '' : col == 'O' ? false : col == 'N' && 0.00}'`);
    });
  });
}
```

---

### Demo

*E.g. **Framing** tab was selected from the drop-down on the **Summary** sheet tab. 

Here's the log result:*

[image]

Comment: I hope this answer helps you with your project. Feel free to comment in case something’s missing.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful. I appreciate your review